# Can't find driver for sqlsrv when running a cron job

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, rhel, sqlsrv

I run a Laravel application on a RHEL server. The database is on an external SQL SERVER.
When running the web application there's no problem with database connection.

When running the CRON job, which calls

```
$ php artisan schedule:run
```

the application can't find the driver for Sql server.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved: the cron job execution was using a different version of PHP. Different both from the one from Apache and from the one from the CLI.
So I just used the explicit path, referencing the correct PHP version.

I was sure it should have used the CLI version but it wasn't, I'm not sure why. Probably due to wrong aliases.

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with your setup on the webserver and out of it. You might try running [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.phpinfo.php) from within your app and from the command line and see if there are any differences that stick out.

Comment: I checked both php -i from console and phpinfo() from the application. They have the same version, same sqlsrv extensions and same php.ini

What else could I check?

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure the driver is installed? You may want to try re-installing it through the system. If the driver exists then maybe it is in a weird place(installed through source code with non-default location for things). In any case phpinfo seems confused, if you see sqlsrv in phpinfo with a location, make sure it actually exists in that location.